# Do all of the OpenCV functions work fine on ROS?

Tags: ros, opencv, image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I decide to do some image processing on ROS, and first I did the same job on VS2013 with OpenCV2.4.9 on windows, I am wondering if it is true that almost every functions like cvCvtColor or every data type including cv::Mat works fine on ROS, I have checked the opencv version on my Ubuntu and it returns 2.4.9 which is why I used 2.4.9 on windows. Does anyone know whether it is a good idea to try on VS first and then make the rest work on ROS. Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228685/do-all-of-the-opencv-functions-work-fine-on-ros?/) by [Henschel.X](https://answers.ros.org/users/26183/henschel.x/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2016-03-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS and OpenCV are two seperate things, which in general do not interfere. So yes, everything will work on ROS.

The only problem (I can think of) that you might get is with the OpenCV version. If you install a ROS package that depends on OpenCV 3, it might be hard to use OpenCV 2.x instead (if you insist on using 2.x in your code).

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2016-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Henschel.X](https://answers.ros.org/users/26183/henschel.x/) on 2016-03-10**:
How can I know about my ROS package depends on OpenCV 2 or 3 may I ask?

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2016-03-11**:
`apt-cache rdepends <package_name>` for those installable from the repositories. For packages "from source": `rosdep keys <package_name>`, but that may be incomplete and you might need to check CMakeLists.txt for something like find_package(OpenCV ...)

**Comment by [Henschel.X](https://answers.ros.org/users/26183/henschel.x/) on 2016-03-13**:
Thank you very much!